# Does SessionAwareMessageListener require commit() / rollback()?

Tags: spring, jms

We're using Spring's `SessionAwareMessageListener`. It seems you are required to manually `commit()` or `rollback()` to make sure a message is consumed or marked for redelivery. But I was wondering if you could also leave it out, and then expect the `SessionAwareMessageListener` to auto commit if no exception occurs or rollback if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here's my answer:
No, a `SessionAwareMessageListener` does not "require" a `commit()` or a `rollback()` by itself. You can have code in the listener without these calls and the listener would still consume messages and assume all of them went through without a problem, unless an exception is thrown from the `onMessage()` method.

For the `commit()` and `rollback()` calls to do what they are intended to do, you'll have to be using a transacted session. This can be done by setting the `sessionTransacted` flag to `true` on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, or by defining and attaching your own transaction manager to the container.